# SQL-Error when submitting an entry with Tags

Tags: solspace, solspace-tag

When trying to create an entry which has a Tag-field in it, I got the following error. (Please note, when creating a entry in a channel that has NO Tag-field, I get no error).

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'sv_dev.t.tag_id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by:
SELECT `t`.`tag_id`, COUNT(e.tag_id) AS count FROM (`exp_tag_tags` t) LEFT JOIN `exp_tag_entries` e ON `e`.`tag_id` = `t`.`tag_id` GROUP BY `e`.`tag_id`
```

Additional info:
Database server
Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
Server type: MySQL
Server version: 5.7.12-0ubuntu1 - (Ubuntu)
Protocol version: 10
Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

Web server
Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev
PHP version: 7.0.4-7ubuntu2.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After google'ing this (and being a MySQL-n00b), I got an answer from Solspace that confirmed what I needed to do:

> Hi Pontus,
>
> I spoke with a developer here and mentioned that this has to do with
>   MySQL 5.7 having SQL_MODE set to "only_full_group_by". If this is the
>   particular issue, the only way around it would be disabling that by
>   running this query in your database:
>
> `SET GLOBAL sql_mode = "STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION";`
>
> Otherwise, there's nothing we can really do about the issue for Tag
>   unfortunately.
>
> Kelsey Martens Director of Software Operations

This worked for me, hope it helps people with similar issues.